# AngularJS: Create two way binding $scope with ngDialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I call ngDialog in `mainController` with option `controller: 'otherController'`  and this gives me the ability to use the `mainController` $scope in `otherController`, but none of the $scope variables created in `otherController` are available for the `mainController`. My question is, how can I access the `otherController` variables in the `mainController`?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to get around the point of scope, which is to encapsulate the data of lower-levels of the application. Parent scopes aren't supposed to see stuff in child scopes. They can listen for events or expose an API for exceptional cases.

Comment: ui-bootstrap's $modal also attach to $rootScope. but personally I abused the Service, and instantiate the service with $scope to get a instance attach to the scope I specified.

Answer (score 0):

While not the best option, you could put the parts you want to transcend the scope into your [root scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope), which is accessible from the entire application.